# What steps do I need to take to insert a indexmenu?

Tags: plugins, dokuwiki

I am updating out dokuwiki and redid it from zero because in out old version are errors that i cant fix. Now I downloaded the indexmenu plugin and put it in the right folder. How and which documents do I need to modify to add the treestructure to a not yet existing sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a page named `sidebar` (unless the name changed in the config), into the root or the namespace you want, and put among other contents an `{{indexmenu}}` tag into it. It has a lot of options, so check the documentation.
Note that there is also a `rightsidebar` for some templates.

Comment: I wonder if you could help commit to this on Area51? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=NTc4MjBmMTE2MTY5MGI3ZWM2ZmU4NGNjNTVlNWI1YTlmZDE3NmRmOTEzNTMzYWM3OTRiNjQ4ZDY2ZjI0OTAwOLzo5TP4sa2hurmNL0TjR9ugGJmjy968m_5q945k1V0a0 I ask because you were one of the earliest followers of the proposal!